# Importing single record using read_json in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to import a json file using the function:

```
sku = pandas.read_json('https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?product_sku=125T:FT0111')
```

However, i keep getting the following error

> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

What should I do to import it correctly into a dataframe?

this is the structure of the json:

```
{
"id": "5",
"sku": "JOSH:BECO-BRN",
"last_updated": "2013-06-10 15:46:22",

...

"propertyType1": [
    "manufacturer_colour"
],
"category": [
    {
        "category_id": "10",
        "category_name": "All Products"
    },

    ...

    {
        "category_id": "238",
        "category_name": "All Sofas"
    }
],
"root_categories": [
    "516"
],
"url": "/p/Beco Suede Sofa Bed?product_id=5",
"item": [
    "2"
],
"image_names": "[\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/L\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-1.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/P\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-1.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/SP\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-1.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/SS\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-1.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/ST\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-1.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/WP\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-1.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/L\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-2.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/P\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-2.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/SP\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-2.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk \\/images\\/products\\/SS\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-2.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/ST\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-2.jpg\",\"https:\\/\\/cdn.worldstores.co.uk\\/images\\/products\\/WP\\/19\\/Beco_Suede_Sofa_Bed-2.jpg\"]"
```

}

Comment: I need to create a self contained python script that processes several json files

Comment: Can you describe how you envision the structure will translate to a dataframe? Do you wish to flatten the nested structure?

Comment: I have added the json structure

Comment: I had this same issue. I solved it by appending '[' ']' to the beginning and end of the JSON and setting the orient="records".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The `pandas.read_json` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) takes multiple formats.

Since you did not specify which format your json file is in (`orient=` attribute), pandas will default to believing your data is columnar. The different formats pandas expects are discussed below.

The data that **you** are trying to parse from https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?product_sku=125T:FT0111
Does **not seem to conform to any of the supported formats** as it seems to be only a single "record". Pandas expects some kind of collection.

You probably should try to collect multiple entries into a single file, *then* parse it with the `read_json` function.

EDIT:

### Simple way of getting multiple rows and parsing it with the `pandas.read_json` function:

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd


url_base = "https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?product_sku={}"
products = ["125T:FT0111", "125T:FT0111", "125T:FT0111"]

raw_data_list = []

for sku in products:
    url = url_base.format(sku)
    raw_data_list.append(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

data = "[" + (",".join(raw_data_list)) + "]"
data = pd.read_json(data, orient='records')
data
```

/EDIT

#### My take on the pandas.read_json function formats.

[The `pandas.read_json` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) is yet another shining example of pandas trying to jam as much functionality as possible into a single function. This leads of course to a very very complicated function.

## Series

If your data is a `Series`, `pandas.read_json(orient=)` defaults to `'index'`

The values allowed for orient while parsing a `Series` are: `{'split','records','index'}`

Note that the Series index must be unique for `orient='index'`.

## DataFrame

If your data is a `DataFrame`, `pandas.read_json(orient=)` defaults to `'columns'`

The values allowed for orient while parsing a `DataFrame` are:
`{'split','records','index','columns','values'}`

Note that the Series index must be unique for `orient='index'` and `orient='columns'`, and the DataFrame columns must be unique for `orient='index'`, `orient='columns'`, and `orient='records'`.

## Format

No matter if your data is a `DataFrame` or a `Series`, the `orient=` will expect data in the same format:

### Split

Expects a string representation of a dict like what the `DataFrame` constructor takes:

```
{"index":[1,2,3,4], "columns":["col1","col2"], "data":[[8,7,6,5], [5,6,7,8]]}
```

### Records

Expects a string representation of a list of dicts like:

```
[{"col1":8,"col2":5},{"col1":7,"col2":6},{"col1":6,"col2":7},{"col1":5,"col2":8}]
```

Note there is no index set here.

### Index

Expects a string representation of a nested dict dict like:

```
{"1":{"col1":8,"col2":5},"2":{"col1":7,"col2":6},"3":{"col1":6,"col2":7},"4":{"col1":5,"col2":8}}
```

Good to note is that it won't accept indicies of other types than strings. May be fixed in later versions.

### Columns

Expects a string representation of a nested dict like:

```
{"col1":{"1":8,"2":7,"3":6,"4":5},"col2":{"1":5,"2":6,"3":7,"4":8}}
```

### Values

Expects a string representation of a list like:

```
[[8, 5],[7, 6],[6, 7],[5, 8]]
```

### Resulting dataframe

In most cases, the dataframe you get will look like this, with the json strings above:

```
   col1  col2
1     8     5
2     7     6
3     6     7
4     5     8
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the most elegant solution however gives me back what I want, or at least I believe so, feel free to warn if something is wrong

```
url = "https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?product_sku=125T:FT0111"
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(data)
data = pd.DataFrame(data.items())
data = data.transpose()
```

Comment: I improved on this version in my answer and still use pd.read_json.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a try except.

```
json_path='https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?product_sku=125T:FT0111'
try: a=pd.read_json(json_path)
except ValueError: a=pd.read_json("["+json_path+"]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating on @firelynx's answer:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

products = ["125T:FT0111", "125T:FT0111", "125T:FT0111"]
raw_lines = ""
for sku in products:
    url = f"https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?product_sku={sku}"
    raw_lines += urlopen(url).read() + "\n"

data = pd.read_json(raw_lines, lines=True)
```

This would support any source returning a single JSON object or a bunch of newline ('\n') separated ones.

Or this one-liner(ish) should work the same:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd

products = ["125T:FT0111", "125T:FT0111", "125T:FT0111"]
data = pd.concat(
    pd.read_json(
        f"https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?product_sku={sku}",
        lines=True
    ) for sku in products
)
```

PS: python3 is only for fstring support here, so you should use str.format for python2 compatibility.